# Find the area of the largest rectangle in a 2D binary matrix with all corners as 1's

Tags: algorithm, optimization, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I have seem similar questions on SO but they have the additional constraint of having all 0's or all 1's inside the rectangle.

- The objective here is to find the largest rectangle (by area) with all 4 corners as 1's.
- The contents of the elements inside the rectangle don't matter.

Example:

```
110101
011000
010001
010101
101101
```

Here the largest rectangle has corner coordinates `(0, 0), (0, 5), (4, 0), (4, 5)` with an area of `5 * 6 = 30`.

One way I could think of was to keep a record of the column indexes of all 1's in a row in a HashMap and with every row check if we have seen a 1 earlier in the same column index. How would you optimize this?

Comment: It sounds like you'd like suggestions on how to optimize your approach; however, the outline you've provided isn't quite complete (how exactly would you compute the rectangle area from your hashmap approach?). I'd suggest posting an implementation/pseudocode and/or analysis. That way we'd be able to provide concrete improvements/suggestions to help you out.

Comment: I'm not too clear on that approach as well. I'll figure out a naive implementation that at least *works*.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

1. Go row-wise and search for every 'corner-pair', biggest first
2. Search column-wise to the corner-pair a matching rectangle, biggest first. Take the current biggest rectangle into account to stop the search earlier.
3. Go to next row and start with 1.